# trying to avoid null pointer exception in the below loop

Tags: java

Please advise is the below check is correct as as i am trying to avoid the null pointer exception , folks please advise how to overcome from this

```
if ((Integer.valueOf(subProductTolerancesMap.get(subProduct))!= null) && (Integer.valueOf(subProductTolerancesMap.get(maxSubProduct))!=null) )
{}
```

Comment: Hint: `Integer.valueOf` will *never* return null...

Comment: so please advise how should we check

Comment: do you need both values?

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct.  If your subProductTolerancesMap is null, you will get a NullPointerException with that code.

Further, if subProductTolerancesMap.get(subProduct) is null or if subProductTolerancesMap.get(maxSubProduct) is null, you will get a NumberFormatException.